# For 500 kg less flour

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Your colleague sent me a invoice today. But he issued it for  **500 kg less flours than my order.**

> Your colleague sent me a invoice today. But he issued it for **the **flours 500 kg less  than my order****

Where should I use the phrase in these sentence? Does both have the same meaning or different meaning?

Comment: "flour" is not "countable" in your context, so it must be in the singular form. Other than that your first example is fine. Your second example makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, 'flour' is singular.

Your first example: "... he issued it for 500 kg less flour than my order." is normal/correct usage.